# Getting timeout error while downloading list of images from server using Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am trying to download a list of images (JPEG format). But I am not able to download any image, and I am getting a timeout error only. I am trying populate list of images in a `RecyclerView`. I even customised the timeout of `Glide` using `Volley` but no luck.
Here is the timeout configuration of the `Glide` using `Volley`:

```
public class CustomGlide implements GlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
        RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue( // Parameters hardcoded from Volley.newRequestQueue()
                new DiskBasedCache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "volley")),
                new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack())) {
            @Override public <T> Request<T> add(Request<T> request) {
                request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 1, 1));
                return super.add(request);
            }
        };
        queue.start();
        glide.register(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new VolleyUrlLoader.Factory(queue));
    }
}
```

This is what I am using to download list of images from server using `Glide`.

```
@Override
public void onBindItemViewHolder(final KolamViewHolder holder, final int itemPosition) {
    Log.e("BaseAdapter", galleryList.get(itemPosition).getImage());
    Glide.with(context).load(galleryList.get(itemPosition).getImage().trim())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .dontAnimate()
            .override(150,150)
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model,
                                   Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model,
                                       Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache,
                                       boolean isFirstResource) {
            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
    }).into(holder.kolamImage);
}
```

Comment: I wish more people in the Android tag would post questions like this. Good job!